# Sampling and Calculation in R

Tags: r

I have a file that contains two columns (Time , VA). The file is large and I managed to read it in R(used read and subset -not a practical for large file). Now, I want to do sampling based on the time, where each sample has a sample size and sample shift. Sample size is fixed value for the whole process of sampling e.g. sampleSize=10 second. Sample shift is the start point for each new sample (after First sample). For example, if sampleShift =4 sec and the sampleSize is 10 sec , that means the second sample will start from 5 sec and add 10 sec as the sample sample size=10 sec. For each sample I want feed the 
-VA- values to a function to some calculation.

```
Sampling <- function(values){
# Perform the sampling 
lastRowNumber<- #specify the last row manually
sampleSize<-10
lastValueInFile<-lastRowNumber-sampleSize

for (i in 1: (lastValueInFile ) ){ 
  EndOfShift<-9+i
  sample<-c(1:sampleSize)
  h<-1

  for(j in i:EndOfShift){        
    sample[h] <- values[j,1]
    h<-h+1
  }
  print(sample)
  #Perform the Calculation on the extracted sample
  #--Samp_Calculation<-SomFunctionDoCalculation(sample) 
}
}
```

The problems with my try are:
1) I have to specify the lastRow number manually for each file I read.
2) I was trying to do the sampling based on rows number not the Time value. Also, the shift was by one for each sample.

file sample:

```
Time     VA
0.00000 1.000
0.12026 2.000
0.13026 2.000
0.14026 2.000
0.14371 3.000
0.14538 4.000
 ..........
 ..........
15.51805 79.002
15.51971 79.015
15.52138 79.028
15.52304 79.040
15.52470 79.053
.............
```

Any suggestion for more professional way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've generated some test data as follows:

```
val <- data.frame (time=seq(from=0,to=15,by=0.01),VA=c(0:1500))
```

... then the function:

```
sampTime <- function (values,sampTimeLen) 
{
    # return a data frame for a random sample of the data frame -values-
    # of length -sampTimeLen-
    minTime <- values$time[1]
    maxTime <- values$time[length(values$time)] - sampTimeLen
    startTime <- runif(1,minTime,maxTime)
    values[(values$time >= startTime) & (values$time <= (startTime+sampTimeLen)),]
}
```

... can be used as follows:

```
> sampTime(val,0.05)
    time  VA
857 8.56 856
858 8.57 857
859 8.58 858
860 8.59 859
861 8.60 860
```

... which I think is what you were looking for.

(EDIT)

Following the clarification that you want a sample from a specific time rather than a random time, this function should give you that:

```
sampTimeFrom <- function (values,sampTimeLen,startTime) 
{
    # return a data frame for sample of the data frame -values-
    # of length -sampTimeLen- from a specific -startTime-
    values[(values$time >= startTime) & (values$time <= (startTime+sampTimeLen)),]
}
```

... which gives:

```
> sampTimeFrom(val,0.05,0)
  time VA
1 0.00  0
2 0.01  1
3 0.02  2
4 0.03  3
5 0.04  4
6 0.05  5
> sampTimeFrom(val,0.05,0.05)
   time VA
6  0.05  5
7  0.06  6
8  0.07  7
9  0.08  8
10 0.09  9
11 0.10 10
```

If you want multiple samples, they can be delivered with `sapply()` like this:

```
> samples <- sapply(seq(from=0,to=0.15,by=0.05),function (x) sampTimeFrom(val,0.05,x))
> samples[,1]
$time
[1] 0.00 0.01 0.02 0.03 0.04 0.05

$VA
[1] 0 1 2 3 4 5
```

In this case the output will overlap but making the `sampTimeLen` very slightly smaller than the shift value (which is shown in the `by=` parameter of the `seq`) will give you non-overlapping samples. Alternatively, one or both of the criteria in the function could be changed from `>=` or `<=` to `>` or `<`.

Comment: Yes this almost what I was looking for. However, instead of the random sample I need to do the sampling on all of the Time content uniformly. In other words, I want to have more samples until the end of the time (no more to sample). sample 2 and 3,..... will be regulated by sampleShift. I tried to add more to your answer, However, I'm getting only one sample. '                                  startTime<-0
  for (i in 1:maxTime){
    startTime <- minTime+startTime
    test<-sampTime(values,sampTimeLen,startTime)
    cat("Sample ",i,"\n")
    print(test)
    startTime<-shiftSize
    
  }'

Comment: @Eng.Mohd: I've edited my answer in a way that hopefully addresses your clarification.